# how to deserialize based on one field value in payload in Spring Kafka?

Tags: spring-kafka

I need consume from kafka same topic with different types. The content of different types are slightly. But they are different. Inside payload of the message, there is one field named type which could determine which javatype it should be deserialized to.
It a little bit difficult for me because to fetch field value of 'type'. I need do a deserialize already.

Is there good way to do this with spring kafka?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What serialization tool do you use? What is your data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Artem Bilan` pointed out in the comments, it'd be easier to help if you added more details to your question. I'll try to help by making some assumptions.

When using `Avro`, deserialization of different payload types should be handled (and enforced) by the `schema-registry` first, such as documented [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/multiple-event-types-in-the-same-kafka-topic/), and this doesn't seem to be compatible with having type information inside the payload, so I'll assume you're talking about `JSON` payloads.

If possible, you should probably change the design to have that kind of metadata in the `record headers` - this way you don't need to deserialize the payload in order to access it, and can use `Spring Kafka` built in tools such as [DelegatingDeserializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#using-headers).

<s>Considering both initial assumptions are right - you're using `JSON` and can't change the design to use `headers` for type metadata, you should be able to implement a custom [JsonTypeResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonTypeResolver.html) to be set on the [JsonDeserializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonDeserializer.html), where you can use an [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to deserialize the payload to, for example, a `Map` - you can then fetch the type information from there and associate it with the proper [JavaType](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType.html).</s>

EDIT: A more performant solution would be to implement a custom deserializer where you can use the ‘readTree’ method in ‘ObjectMapper’ to deserialize the payload to a ‘JsonNode’. You can then traverse this object to fetch type information, and use the ‘treeToValue’ method to continue deserializing the json node to the proper type. That way you’re only deserializing it once.

Comment: Hi Tomaz, U are assumption are right. we have json. Not using schema-registry. Not have message header. Do determine different types, I need de-serialize json payload. Now i did it with spring kafka where a method based type determination provided. Inside the determination method, deserialize the payload, then return based the field 'type' determine pojo type. But I do not like my idea because it do two times de-serialization.

Comment: Sure, makes sense. You can also implement a custom deserializer where you can use the ‘readTree’ method in ‘ObjectMapper’ to deserialize the payload to a ‘JsonNode’. You can then traverse this object to fetch type information, and use the ‘treeToValue’ method to deserialize the json node to the proper type. That way you’re only deserializing it once.

Comment: Edited my answer with this solution - please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Many thanks. It works for me after implement a custom de-serializer.  I will also discuss with colleagues about use the header with a type info in.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If the implementation you used was what was described in this answer, please mark it as accepted to let other users know. Thanks